# Using javascript I would like to add an image as a link, but would like to change the image about every third time someone visits

Tags: javascript

Say I have two images uploaded to my server:
http://mywebsite.com/image1.jpg and
http://mywebsite.com/image2.jpg

I would like to display image1.jpg on my website two times, so that when clicked, it goes to: http:// gohere.com
But about every third time, I would like image2.jpg displayed with the same link.

Thank you for all the help,
Jones

(I would really appreciate the whole code, I'm guessing it's not that long, and random would be fine for me. Say generate a random number between 1 and 3, and if it can be divided by 3, image2 can be used.)

Comment: You need to persist data between requests. You can do this either server-side using the database, or through the session / cookies. This may help you with the latter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484350/877472

Comment: I used the word "about" because random would be fine for me. Say generate a number between 1 and 3, and if it can be divided by 3, image2 can be used. But I don't know how I would code it, that's why I need help. Thank you!

Comment: Break the problem into smaller components and research each. You have three pieces to your puzzle: how to generate a random number within a range, how to store it between requests, and how to switch one image in a link for another (hint: use jQuery). You have a link that helps you with the second, find answers to the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several solutions here.

If you have a server-side code, you can do this on the page generation, with either some random number generation or by keeping a counter of the number of times the page has been loaded and check if that value is a multiple of 3.

The other solution is to do this in JavaScript, and the random solution is probably better here.

Try using this HTML for the image

```
<a href="http://gohere.com"><img id="my-image" /></a>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.ready = function() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("my-image");

        if (Math.random() < 0.67) {
            myImage.src = "http://mywebsite.com/image1.jpg";
        } else {
            myImage.src = "http://mywebsite.com/image2.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wow!! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for understanding my needs and delivering the PERFECT solution! Thanks again, thanks a million!

Have a nice day, all the best,
Jones

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply swapping between 1 and 2 randomly with jQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rdm = Math.round(Math.random()) + 1;
    $('img').attr('src', 'http://mywebsite.com/image' +  rdm + '.jpg');
});
```

Comment: Avoid using jQuery when not necessary and not already used by the post-owner. And he would like a probability of 1/3 for the second image, not 1/2.